# How to process a well structured text similar to excel sheet in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I was fetching data from a text file and saving it to a database by using ado.net code. Textfile contains data in the form: column , row format, but I dont know what went wrong, I am missing certain datas from textfile.  The code used is shown below

```
 string filename = @"D:\EMS_DATA\firstfile.txt";
 string[] rows = null;
 string[] cols = null;
 int counter = 0;
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
 {
     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg)).ToArray();
     cols = lines[0].Trim().Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
     {
         rows = line.Trim().Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

         for (int i = counter; i <cols.Length; i++)
         {
             for (int j = counter; j <rows.Length; j++)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("values are {0}{1}", cols[counter], rows[counter]);
                 ++counter;
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Texfile is in the format shown below

```
firstname  lastname  salary  age
sasi   kiran    88000   32
ravi   kiran    92000   23
jafer  sharif   34000   45
kiran  bedi     45000   34
```

Comment: What data is missing?  And what is the output using that text file as input?

Comment: Why are you creating a `StreamReader` and then just using `File.ReadAllLines` instead?

Comment: certain rows are not coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the `StreamReader` if you are not going to use it. Second you don't need two nested `for` loops.  Then actually use the `for` loop variable in your code.  Also guard against lines that have fewer entries than the header.  Finally you can add a variable to keep track of the current line.

```
string filename = @"D:\EMS_DATA\firstfile.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    .Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg)).ToArray();
string[] cols = lines[0].Trim()
    .Split(new[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int line = 1;
foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    string[] cells = line.Trim()
        .Split(new[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < cols.Length; counter++)
    {
        string cellValue = "N/A";
        if(counter < cells.Length)
            cellValue = cells[counter];
        Console.WriteLine(
            "values at row {0} column {1} are {2} : {3}", 
            line, 
            counter, 
            cols[counter], 
            cellValue);
    }

    line++;
}
```

Comment: That's a typo.  Should have been 'cellValue'.  It's fixed now.

Comment: perfect ,let me do additional testing