# How to fetch data from an excel sheet which contains data in row column format?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, random-access

I have an excel sheet where first row is column names and rest all are rows.

I am reading an excel sheet values by using the following code, but my requirement is to (instead of getting all the values in a sequence) get data as-if indexed by `columnname , row`. How to get them like this?

Existing code which I am using is:

```
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    Excel.Range range;
    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    int cCnt = 0;
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Copy of Macro with Radio_Test.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
    {
        for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
        {
            str = (Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2));
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

same like [How to process a well structured text similar to excel sheet in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217579/how-to-process-a-well-structured-text-similar-to-excel-sheet-in-c-sharp)
but here it is for excel file ,ther it was text files and same logic not working for excel file,mainly i filed to convert range.rows to string arrays and even for columns

**UPDATE**

is it a complicated task, if some body can give me conversion for the following two line is sufficient

```
string[] rows = range.rows; // here exception for converion
string[] cols = range.columns;// here also
```

UDPATE

any updates? or we cant do that way??

Comment: what is column name? A1, B1? or values from 1st row?

Comment: no from all rows,so it will be like columnname then corresponding rows values

Comment: similarly like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217579/how-to-process-a-well-structured-text-similar-to-excel-sheet-in-c-sharp